# Just set the TTL on a row

Tags: cassandra

Using Java, can I scan a Cassandra table and just update the TTL of a row? I don't want to change any data. I just want to scan Cassandra table and set TTL of a few rows.

Also, using java, can I set TTL which is absolute. for example (2016-11-22 00:00:00). so I don't want to specify the TTL in seconds, but specify the absolute value in time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Cassandra doesn't allow to set the TTL value for a **row**, it allows to set TTLs for columns **values** only.

In the case you're wondering why you **are** experiencing **rows** *expiration*, this is because if **all** the values of all the columns of a record are TTLed then the row disappears when you try to `SELECT` it.

However, this is only true if you perform an `INSERT` with the `USING TTL`. If you `INSERT` without TTL and then do an `UPDATE` with TTL you'll still see the row, but with null values. Here's a few examples and some gotchas:

---

### Example with a TTLed `INSERT` only:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    k text PRIMARY KEY,
    v int,
);

INSERT INTO test (k,v) VALUES ('test', 1) USING TTL 10;

... 10 seconds after...

SELECT * FROM test ;

 k             | v
---------------+---------------
```

---

### Example with a TTLed `INSERT` and a TTLed `UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO test (k,v) VALUES ('test', 1) USING TTL 10;
UPDATE test USING TTL 10 SET v=0 WHERE k='test';

... 10 seconds after...

SELECT * FROM test;

 k             | v
---------------+---------------
```

---

### Example with a non-TTLed `INSERT` with a TTLed `UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO test (k,v) VALUES ('test', 1);
UPDATE test USING TTL 10 SET v=0 WHERE k='test';

... 10 seconds after...

SELECT * FROM test;

 k             | v
---------------+---------------
          test |          null
```

Now you can see that the only way to solve you problem is to rewrite **all** the values of all the columns of your row with a new TTL.

In addition, there's no way to specify an explicit *expiration date*, but you can get a simple TTL value in **seconds** with simple math (as other suggested).

Have a look at the official [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html) about data expiration. And don't forget to have a look at the [DELETE](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html) section for updating TTLs.

HTH.

Comment: I dug into this a bit recently and noted this.
The simple answer is `INSERT INTO test (k,v) VALUES ('test', 1) USING TTL 10;` will expire a row.

There is a hidden cell that gets created for the key that will get the expiration when inserting.  This cell will only have a TTL on `insert` you can't modify this cell manually. So if you reinsert the entire row you can set a TTL on a row.

If you set the TTL initially on insert, then update the TTL for a column, this will extend the TTL for the row, but as soon as that TTL expires on that column, the entire row is expired.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't only update TTL of a row. You have to update or re-insert all the column.**

You can select all the regular column and the primary keys column then update the regular columns with primary keys or re-insert using TTL in second

In Java you can calculate TTL in second from a date using below method.

```
public static long ttlFromDate(Date ttlDate) throws Exception {
    long ttl = (ttlDate.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;
    if (ttl < 1) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid ttl date");
    }
    return ttl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can set a TTL value on the entire table while creating it.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    k text PRIMARY KEY,
    v int,
) WITH default_time_to_live = 63113904;
```

Above example will create a table whose rows will disappear after 2 years.