# cassandra delete an entire row in the future using TTL after the row was created

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I want to mark an entire existing row (not a column) for deletion using a `TTL`.

Unfortunately the TTL will only remove the entire row if it was set during insertion of the row. If you "update" the row and add a `TTL`, it will only effect the specific columns which were updated , and you can't "update" the primary key.

Is there some sort of work around? Am I forced to read the full row and then "re-insert" it to the table, adding the `TTL` value?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update TTL on an entire row. To do so, you need to re-insert with new TTL.

Check out [This link on: Just set the TTL on a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730510/just-set-the-ttl-on-a-row)

Comment: so what is the suggested way to solve this problem? I have to write the full row again? (read and then write) or is there a design pattern to do it more efficiantly (create a side table or "stored procedure")

Comment: > I have to write the full row again? Yes, all of the column's ttl you want to update.

AFAIK, this is the way to do it. It's because the way Cassandra is designed. C* doesn't store it's entire row altogether and it checks TTL of corresponding columns while you are going to read it.